# Does internal Azure traffic to a load balanced set stay within the cloud service?

Tags: azure

I have two load balanced VMs with a vip in an Azure cloud service.  The vip is a public IP address.  Will other servers within the same cloud service send traffic outside the cloud service to access the vip or will traffic remain internal to the cloud service?  Are there security concerns I should be aware of in this situation - ie, if traffic does indeed travel outside the cloud service, can it be intercepted and do I need to take additional precautions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the traffic to a public load-balanced IP is considered public traffic, even if it originates in Azure.